# How to map a list of items to an Erlang record

Tags: erlang

Erlang beginner here!

I have a list of elements where I would like to map some of the elements to items with a record.

```
List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].
```

I also have a record defined as follows:

```
-record(a_record, { itemA = "", itemB = ""}).
```

I would like to map the list into a tuple that matches the record definition so that I end up with:

```
#a_record{itemA="A", itemB="B" }.
```

I'm looking at the lists module but can't see a clean solution yet.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the elements in your list are in the same order as the record fields to be initialized, and that the list has at least the same number of elements as the record has fields, you can apply a bit of a hack to create an instance of the record from the list by taking advantage of the fact that records are tuples under the covers. For example, your `a_record` is represented as a tuple whose first element is the atom `a_record` followed by 2 elements, one for each record field.

```
1> List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].
["a","b","c","d","e"]
2> rd(a_record, { itemA = "", itemB = ""}).
a_record
3> ARecord = list_to_tuple([a_record|lists:sublist(List,size(#a_record{})-1)]).
#a_record{itemA = "a",itemB = "b"}
```

Command 1 defines our `List`, and in command 2 we use the shell `rd` command to define a record like the one in your question. Command 3 builds a new list composed of the record name as the head and the field initializers as the tail. The `size/1` function gives us the number of fields in the record including its name, so we subtract 1 from that and use the resulting value as the size of the sublist of `List` to use to initialize the record fields. We then pass the resulting list to `list_to_tuple/1`, and as you can see, the result is an `a_record` instance initialized with values from `List`.

Comment: Also note that although this is how you technically do it, it is probably preferable to do it manually by hardcoding the fields and getting each value from the list. That way, when the record length or field order is changed, you don't end up creating invalid records.

Comment: @AdamLindberg your suggestion seems like a safe approach to me as well. When you say manually, do you mean using something like lists:nth to pull each item out of the list and then build the record from those?

Comment: @BrianB: one other thing: though records and maps are not interchangeable, you might consider whether a map might be suitable for your use case, and if so just use [`maps:from_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#from_list-1), though note that you'd need a list of key-value pairs in that case.

Comment: @BrianB,  manually is smth like `[A, B | _] = List, #a_record{itemA =A, itemB =B}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use record_info/2 and list_to_tuple/1:

```
   List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
   List2 = [string:to_upper(P) || P <- lists:sublist(List, record_info(size, a_record)-1)],
   list_to_tuple([a_record | List2]).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're safer doing a list comprehension and actually retrieving the keys out of the map that are associated with fields in the record. You might end up with a record full of undefined fields, but you don't need to do any checking to ensure the map as the same number of keys/values as the record, nor need to be concerned about any order.

```erlang
RecordType = a_record.
RecordFields = record_info(fields, a_record).
Map = #{a_record_field => <<"a record value">>}.
Record = map_to_record(Map, RecordType, RecordFields).
 
map_to_record(Map, RecordType, RecordFields) ->
  RecordValues = [maps:get(RecordField, Map, undefined) || RecordField <- RecordFields],
  AlmostRecord = [RecordType | RecordValues],
  list_to_tuple(AlmostRecord).
```

If your map keys are binary strings, then you'll need to convert the atoms from the list of record fields into binary strings.

It's important to note that `record_info(fields, RecordType)`, is not a valid call to the `record_info` function. I think this is because the return values of `record_info` are determined at compile time due to the syntactic sugar nature of records themselves basically being typed tuples, and a runtime call is invalid.